# How to Append data to an Array in Firebase?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a array called `subscribedTo` in my users node. Now I want to append some `push ID's` to that array whenever a user is subscribed.

But the `push ID` are being replaced instead of getting appended.

How can i append the push ID's to the array?

**Schema**

```
"tester@gmail,com": {
    "email": "tester@gmail,com",
    "hasLoggedInWithPassword": true,
    "name": "tester",
    "subscribedTo": [
      "-KFPi5GjCcGrF-oaHnjr"
    ],
    "timestampJoined": {
      "timestamp": 1459583857967
    }
  }
```

**CODE**

```
public void onSubscribe(View v) {

        final Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

        final HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        pushIDList.add(PROG_ID);
        userMap.put("/" + Constants.FIREBASE_LOCATION_USERS + "/" + mEncodedEmail + "/subscribedTo",
                pushIDList);

        firebaseRef.updateChildren(userMap, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                Toast.makeText(ProgramDetail.this, "You are subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `updateChildren()` with a map, Firebase takes each key and replaces the object at that location with the value from the map.

The Firebase documentation on `updateChildren()` says this about it:

> Given a single key path like `alanisawesome`, `updateChildren()` only updates data at the first child level, and any data passed in beyond the first child level is a treated as a setValue() operation.

So in your case, you are replacing the entire contents of `"/" + Constants.FIREBASE_LOCATION_USERS + "/" + mEncodedEmail + "/subscribedTo"`.

The solution is to either make the `PROG_ID` part of the key in the map:

```
userMap.put("/" + Constants.FIREBASE_LOCATION_USERS + "/" + mEncodedEmail + "/subscribedTo/"+PROG_ID, true);
firebaseRef.updateChildren(userMap, ...
```

Or to simply call `setValue()` at the lower location in the JSON tree:

```
firebaseRef.child("/" + Constants.FIREBASE_LOCATION_USERS + "/" + mEncodedEmail + "/subscribedTo/"+PROG_ID).setValue(true);
```

You'll note that in both cases I got rid of your array in favor of the [recommended structure for such a so-called index](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html):

```
"subscribedTo": {
  "-KFPi5GjCcGrF-oaHnjr": true
},
```