# Push data to Firebase array

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database

I am aware that this question has been answered a few times but I am not satisfied with any of those solutions. In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659654/how-to-append-data-to-an-array-in-firebase) the final structure doesn't really look like array.

My solution was to get the data "array" from FireBase and then use the lenght of the data as a key. Here is the code:

```
           var objectToSave = {};
            objectToSave[Object.keys(this.officeArray).length] = officeID
            this.$.user_office_document.ref.update(objectToSave);
```

This solution works but it requires fetching the data which hopefully shouldn't be necessary.

Thanks

Comment: There are very good reasons why Firebase doesn't use arrays for its collections. The need to have a synchronized copy of the data in order to be able to append is one of them. I recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and then switching over to the way the [Firebase documentation treats lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists)

Comment: Ok, I realized I might run into synchronization issues. I simple need to store a set of unique values (firebase ids) and I don't care about the index. I guess I'll just use {value: true} and iterate over the keys when needed. Thanks

Comment: The `value: true` pattern is indeed perfect for that. It's how you model a set in Firebase (given that there must always be a value for each key).